# Why is there "class" in "template <class x>"?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

What does the "class" part of a template statement do?

Example:

```
template <class T>
class Something
{
    public:
        Something(const T &something);
}
```

And what else can go there?  I usually only see "class".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `class` keyword means the same thing as the `typename` keyword for the most part. They both indicates that T is a type.

The only difference between the keywords `class` and `typename` is that `class` can be used to provide class template template arguments to a template, whereas `typename` can't. Consider:

```
template<template <class T> class U> // must be "class"
std::string to_string(const U<char>& u)
{
  return std::string(u.begin(),u.end());
}
```

The only other thing you can put in place of the `class` or `typename` keywords is an integral type. For example:

```
template<std::size_t max>
class Foo{...};
...
Foo<10> f;
```

For a concrete example of this, take a look at `std::bitset<N>` in the standard library.

Comment: Just a small point about template template declarations: template <template <typename> class> is allowed (only the name of the template needs to be precededed specifically by 'class'). It's quite a strange rule.

Comment: Actually, "class" and "typename" can both be used to introduce template type arguments. Template template arguments are introduced by "template". The "class" in template template arguments makes it clear you can't instantiate that template with a function template.

Answer (score 8):

To define a template parameter, you need either to tell the compiler the parameter is a type, or a value.

### In the begining...

If I remember correctly, the C++ committee was reluctant to add a new keyword to the C++ language, and so, they decided to authorize the following notations:

```
template<int I>
int getTwice()
{
   return I * 2 ;
}

template<class T>
std::string getType(const T & t)
{
   return typeid(t).name() ;
}

void doSomething()
{
   std::cout << "25 : " << getTwice<25>() << std::endl ;
   std::cout << "5  : " << getTwice<5>() << std::endl ;

   std::cout << "type(25)   : " << getType(25) << std::endl ;
   std::cout << "type(25.5) : " << getType(25.5) << std::endl ;
   std::cout << "type(abc)  : " << getType("abc") << std::endl ;
}
```

Which outputs, in g++:

```
25 : 50
5  : 10
type(25)   : i
type(25.5) : d
type(abc)  : A4_c
```

The first notation was a template over a value. So, we have the type of the value in the template declaration:

```
// "I" is the value, and "int" is the type of the value
template <int I>
```

The second notation was a template over a unknown type, and the fact that type was not "known" was marked by a "class" keyword. So, in this context, "class" meant "type".

```
// "T" is a type... And "class" is the "this-is-a-type" keyword
template <class T>
```

You'll note that with the second notation, despite the class keyword, T could be... a int, or another build-in type. But then, better to have this curiosity than add a new keyword, don't you agree?...

### Oops...

Everything was good and Ok until someone wrote the following code:

```
template<class T> // T could be any STL container, for example a vector<char>
void printContainerData(const T & t)
{
   std::cout << "aVector:" ;

   for(T::const_iterator it = t.begin(), itEnd = t.end(); it != itEnd; ++it)
   {
      std::cout << " " << (*it) ;
   }

   std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

Where T::const_iterator is a type, of course... But then, it could be a static member of a class of type T, and thus, a value. The compiler could be quite confused.

### In the end...

The solution was to tell the compiler that T::const_iterator was **really** a type... Which would lead with this kind of notation:

```
for(class T::const_iterator it = t.begin(), // etc.
```

But this was thought not possible/correct (class is about classes declarations, no?). So, dragging their feet, they decided a keyword **was** indeed needed to tell the compiler the symbol was a type, and not a value.

"type" was not considered, I guess, because making it a keyword would break a lot of code. So typename was used instead. With typename, we can write:

```
for(typename T::const_iterator it = t.begin(), // etc.
```

And for consistency's sake, we are supposed to use:

```
template <typename T>
```

When T is supposed to be a type, and not a value.
But for compatibility reasons, the old notation:

```
template <class T>
```

is still authorized.

### And what about??

[eben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348730/why-is-there-class-in-template-class-x#348740) proposed an answer above, an answer I wanted to comment, because it is quite interesting:

```
template<template <class T> class U> // must be "class"
std::string to_string(const U<char>& u)
{
  return std::string(u.begin(),u.end());
}
```

I will comment only its "meaning" (this code can't be used with STL containers on my g++ compiler, but this was not the point, I guess): One moment, it puts a constraint over U saying: "U is a class templated over the type T. This is the part:

```
template <class T> class U
```

Which can be also written:

```
template <typename T> class U
```

Because U is really and only a class (and not a built-in type), while T is a type, any type.

And the next line, it says that U is specialized over char:

```
std::string to_string(const U<char>& u)
```

So, this "generic code" will only work for U if U is declared as:

```
template<typename T>
class U
{
   // Etc.
} ;
```

And U is instanciated over a char:

```
U<char> u ;
// etc.
to_string(u)
```

But one thing was forgotten: The notation proposed by Eben can be written two ways:

```
template<template <class T> class U>
std::string to_string(const U<char>& u)

template<template <typename T> class U>
std::string to_string(const U<char>& u)
```

The second "class" keyword is not a "type" keyword per se. It's a type that is a templated class over T. Thus the confusing notation.

Another way of writting Eben's code, removing the constraints above, would be something like:

```
template<typename U>
std::string to_string(const U & u)
{
   return std::string(u.begin(),u.end());
}
```

And let the compiler do its magic:

```
std::list<char> myList ;
// etc.
std::cout << to_string(myList) << std:endl ;
```

(Eben's code didn't work with STL containers templated on "char" on my g++ compiler, for example...)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following as template arguments:

- any integral type `short, int, long, bool`, etc.

  pointers to objects or functions

  references to objects or functions

  pointers to member objects or member functions

A few examples:

```
template<typename T, int N=4, bool Flag>
class myClass { /*...*/ };

template<typename T, const int& Reference, myClass * Pointer>
class someClass { /*...*/ };

template<typename T, int (T::*MemberFunctionPtr)(int, int)>
class anotherClass { /*...*/ };
```

Comment: You're missing template template arguments